Converting R models to PMML using JPMML-R [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException]
I am trying to convert R Model (model info) using JPMML-R. Followed the instructions here , yet encountered the error below when converting the RDS file rf.rds to a PMML file:
INFO: Parsing RDS..
Jul 01, 2024 7:03:21 AM org.jpmml.rexp.example.Main run
SEVERE: Failed to parse RDS
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 23
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:125)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readTag(RExpParser.java:499)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readClosure(RExpParser.java:178)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:76)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readTag(RExpParser.java:499)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readClosure(RExpParser.java:178)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:76)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:515)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:508)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readClosure(RExpParser.java:176)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:76)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:515)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:508)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readFunctionCall(RExpParser.java:214)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:82)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.parse(RExpParser.java:53)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.example.Main.run(Main.java:113)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.example.Main.main(Main.java:101)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 23
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:125)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readTag(RExpParser.java:499)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readClosure(RExpParser.java:178)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:76)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readTag(RExpParser.java:499)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readClosure(RExpParser.java:178)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:76)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:195)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:515)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:508)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readClosure(RExpParser.java:176)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:76)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readEnvironment(RExpParser.java:194)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:78)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readPairList(RExpParser.java:155)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:74)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:515)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readAttributes(RExpParser.java:508)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readFunctionCall(RExpParser.java:214)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:82)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readVector(RExpParser.java:329)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.readRExp(RExpParser.java:97)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpParser.parse(RExpParser.java:53)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.example.Main.run(Main.java:113)
        at org.jpmml.rexp.example.Main.main(Main.java:101)

I am working on

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-113-generic x86_64)
java: openjdk 11.0.23 2024-04-16
Maven: Apache Maven 3.6.3
R: R version 4.3.3

Following command returns error:
java -jar pmml-rexp-example/target/pmml-rexp-example-executable-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar --rds-input rf.rds --pmml-output rf.pmml

